# Magento 2 text input source model

Tags: magento2, product-attribute, input, source-model, text

Has anyone found an example of the product attribute with input type text and a source model?
With a select input type - it is easy, but I cant find anything with text type.

Comment: Why you need for source model simple product text input attribute ?

Comment: We have a custom entity data that must be exported with default product export (product entity and custom entity are related).
We had an idea that we are able to have a source model for the text input - this would solve all the issues.